# Craft second tier of Universal Cable in Minecraft Mekanism

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-mekanism

I found the recipe for only basic cable (tier1). How other cables are crafted?
http://wiki.aidancbrady.com/wiki/Universal_Cable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used NEI and got the recipes by myself:
(every is crafted using first tier)

Advanced

[image: Advanced]

Elite

[image: Elite]

Ultimate

[image: Ultimate]